# UI-Thread seems to lag when downloading data

Tags: java, android, multithreading, javafxports

So I am starting to build up an application that I have already programmed using JavaFX on my computer for android. I am pretty much completely new to android.

What I'm struggling with right now is to download a file smoothly.

I have the following code in my `MyActivity.java` class:

```
/**
 * Called when the user clicks the getWebsite button
 */
public void getWebsite(View view) {

    WebReader web = new WebReader(URL);
    Thread webThread = new Thread(web);
    webThread.start();
    try {
        webThread.join();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(web.getWebsite());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

WebReader implements Runnable. The following method is called on `public void run()`:

```
 private void getWebsite(String URL) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String line = "";
    java.net.URL myUrl = null;
    try {
        myUrl = new URL(URL);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myUrl.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        toReturn = toReturn + "\n" + line;
    }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The whole thing works, I get the website text (rather the text in the file the link directs to - it's a direct download link from Google Drive) displayed on my TextView.

**BUT:** The animation of the pressed Button appears at the same time as the Text, so about 1 sec after I actually pressed it. **I am guessing** that I still somehow put the UI-Thread to sleep while I download the file.

**How can I get the Button to show it's animation when it is pressed?**

PS: I tried working with *intends*, but failed on transferring the data from the *Downloading Intent* to the *UI*... If someone has the time and energy to get a solution with intends going I'd be more then happy to try to understand and implement it!

PPS: If there is anything else you don't like about this code (Threading issues, bad style, etc.) don't hesitate to tell me.
 **Criticism is the only way to learn when trying to teach yourself something!**

Comment: Use an `asyncTask` instead: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is lagging because you are blocking the UI thread until your `webThread` completes by using `webThread.join();`.

Look into using an `AsyncTask` instead. It has a method `doInBackground()` you can override to do all your background work and then once complete you can update your `TextView` with the results in `onPostExecute(Result)` since that is run on the UI thread for you.

Comment: But then I have to update the TextView from the class that extends the `AsyncTask`, don't I?

Comment: Yes but usually an `AsyncTask` is an inner class of where it is used so you will have access to the `TextView` you need to update.

Comment: I will want to update different TextView's with downloaded content though. That would create a jungle of inner classes... :(

Comment: Does this task need to run in multiple different activities or fragments or are all the `TextView`s in the same layout?

Comment: As mentioned, just started out... The main goal would be to load all the content on startup (yet I am faaar away from that at this point).  So for this issue let's just assume they are all in the same layout.

Comment: OK so instead of creating a different nested `AsyncTask` class for each `TextView` you can make the id of the `TextView` you want to update a parameter to the constructor of your `AsyncTask` This way once the task completes you know which `TextView` you need to update in `onPostExecute` since you have its id.

Comment: I'm actually really glad to read this because that is what I've come up with myself just a minute ago. In the long run this will not be any use to me as I'm not updating any TextViews with it, so I'm trying to adopt this to variables rather then TextView id's. But this is getting of topic now, thanks for you help though!